# Main address with router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I use angular 2 with typescript and I create some table application.

I add the router to navigate of my app. And now, the main adress of my project in browser is - `localhost`. How redirect on `localhost` to `localhost/login`.  How to syntax this? It is a part of my app.routing:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
 { component: LaskComponent, path: "table_per" },
 { component: DashboardComponent, path: "dashboard" },
 { component: LoginComponent, path: "login" },
 { component: RootComponent, path: "" },
 { component: HomeComponent, path: "home" },
 { component: NotFoundComponent, path: "not_found" },
 { path: "**", redirectTo: "not_found" },
];

 export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

I mean that I would launch `localhost/login`  when I start application, not `localhost`

Comment: you can add route {path: '', redirectTo: '/login'}. path: '' means 'localhost' or you can say that root of url.

Comment: This is really a basic question and you should either read the doc or ask that on Gitter. Quick answer : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#fetch-data-before-navigating and look for the file app/crisis-center/crisis-center-routing.module.ts (resolve). There's an example

Comment: @Maxime i add this: `{ path: "", pathMatch: "full", redirectTo: "/login" }`, like an in example, and nothings works. My root still `localhost`

Comment: Are your routes even called ? Where do you use your variable `appRoutes` ? Edit the answer with some more relevant code please.

Comment: @Maxime i update the code

Comment: @EduardArevshatyan, remove **slash** from 'redirectTo' attribute **{ path: '', pathMatch: "full", redirectTo: "login" }**

Comment: Did you add `routing` to `@NgModule({imports: [routing], ...})`?

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer  yes, of course

Comment: @codeninja.sj i did it, but it doesnt still works

Comment: What is the current behavior with above suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
 { component: LaskComponent, path: "table_per" },
 { component: DashboardComponent, path: "dashboard" },
 { component: LoginComponent, path: "login" },
 { component: RootComponent, path: "" },
 { component: HomeComponent, path: "home" },
 { component: NotFoundComponent, path: "not_found" },
 { path: "**", redirectTo: "not_found" },
];
```

As you catch `{ component: RootComponent, path: "" }` you will be loading `RootComponent` when the url is `/`.

Instead of that, try :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: '/login'
  },

  { component: LaskComponent, path: 'table_per' },
  { component: DashboardComponent, path: 'dashboard' },
  { component: LoginComponent, path: 'login' },
  { component: HomeComponent, path: 'home' },
  { component: NotFoundComponent, path: 'not_found' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'not_found' }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Empty path routes need `pathMatch: 'full'` when they have no child routes or no `redirectTo`

```
{ component: RootComponent, path: "", pathMatch: "full"},
```

or

```
{ path: "", redirectTo: "/login},
```

Ensure you have `<base href="/">` set as first element in the `<head>` element and ensure the server you're using supports HTML5 pushState.

Comment: Thank you for you qiick answer!